# what is the XmlSampleGenerator namespace?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want use XmlSampleGenerator API in my project. i don't know how to add this my project. i use C# and 4.0 .Net FrameWork. can anbody help me?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302296.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't part of the .NET Framework, it is sample code that is included by the article. You can download the source where it says "Click here to download the code sample for this article."